# npm 3.x and local paths in module's package.json

Tags: npm, package.json

Recently I've installed a new nodejs 5.x with npm 3.x - the most notable change is flat structure in node_modules - that's great thing on Windows environment.

Unfortunately I've noticed that new npm puts local paths in package.json for all installed modules. How can I prevent this (or put there relative path)? I want to commit my node_modules to hg repository, so everyone in development team will have the same modules. Here is a sample stripped package.json from abbrev package:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      "abbrev@https://registry.npmjs.org/abbrev/-/abbrev-1.0.7.tgz",
      "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Documents\\ABC"
    ]
  ],
  "_where": "C:\\Users\\ABC\\Documents\\ABC"
}
```

"C:\Users\ABC\Documents\ABC" is local path

Best Regards,

Comment: Sounds like what `npm shrinkwrap` is for. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap

Comment: Unfortunately shrinkwrapped packages also have local paths written by npm manager.

Comment: I mean you can run `npm shrinkwrap` and commit the resulting file `npm-shrinkwrap.json` into your project — there're no relative paths in this file, just package names and versions. Everyone else checking out this project just installs from this file and gets exactly the same versions. Problem solved. No need to commit the entire `node_modules` and deal with megabytes of diff logs.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that repository does not contain all needed modules - we are using Jenkis build tool and we would like to avoid fetching all the modules with every build (we are cleaning up the workspace every time).

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Nope, but here are links to similar issues:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9717

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10393

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in npm@5 , npm@5 is officially released

> `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: Does this actually work for anybody? I still get `package.json` files with `_where` including full absolute path and `npm --version` says `6.14.10`.

Comment: As explained in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10393 it seems that `npm` uses properties starting with an underscore (like `_where`) as a poor man's log instead of implementing proper logging for `npm install`. Nobody seems to know why they do it like this.